# Deactivate shortcut launching airplay

Tags: macos, airplay, shortcut

Everytime I use cmd + shift + p (which is used in a lot of advanced text editor like sublime to open the command palette) my mac opens a window [image: asking me to enter the airplay code].

I don't want this mac to be connected to airplay.

I've looked at all airplay settings in system preferences as well as the keyborad shortcuts one. I even set a global cmd + shift + p on an arbitrary command to make it conflict with the airplay one, without success.

Installing keycues and cheatsheet didn't help me find it.

Answer (score 2):

[Noizio](http://noiz.io) was actually at fault here. The application maps `Command + Shift + P` as its "Play/Pause" hotkey, overriding Sublime's own hotkey for the Command Palette. I modified the hotkey for Noizio to a different key pattern, and the issue was resolved.

Comment: We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions